# mockview when trying to preview form

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin in Visual Studio. When I click on Design to preview my form, all I see is MockView on an orange background. I have tried to find a solution but nothing has made any difference. I tried Clean Solution then Build Solution. I have the latest version of Java. I downloaded HotReload and enabled it but it's the same. I have it in Debug mode. I have the latest version of Visual Studio. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: The issue will appear when the layout has issue (for example missing a `<` or `/` ). You could post the code of Layout.xml , which will be helpful to solve the issue .

Comment: It's the default code for a blank cross-platform app:

Comment: Did you try to run it directly ?

Comment: No, I can't run it on my phone because the driver won't install, and the emulator won't run either

Comment: Delete the folder  `bin` and `obj` in your project , then clean and rebuild it .

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: Try to re-install the IDE and test again .

Comment: No luck with that either

Comment: check this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/904999/xamarin-forms-xaml-preview-not-working-shows-orang.html

Comment: it says VS has fixed the issue in VS2019 16.6, if update in VS installer can't solve the issue, I suggest you completely uninstall Visual Studio and reinstall it again. A complete uninstall includes fully delete the VS folder in your computer(usually it's under: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio). If the completely re-install does not work either, I suggest you report the problem in DevCommunity(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)